# HTTP 401.1 all of the sudden after a server reboot

Tags: sql-server, iis, iis-6, replication

I am running SQL Server CE replication on a web server and recently replications have been failing.  When I try to visit the diag utility (http://webaddress/Replication/SqlCeSa30.dll?Diag I get an http 401.1.

```
HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
Internet Information Services (IIS)
```

The website is setup for anonymous access in Directory Security, the file ACL permissions are all correct (and have not changed) and I re-ran the ConWizard.exe tool which said that everything was still ok.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems the issue was the Anonymous User account.  Somehow it got its password change/corrupted.  I reset the password in AD and updated it in IIS, and the SQL Server replication agent and everything is working fine again.  Weird.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure only anonymous access is enabled for this site, you can check KB909887 for more information. Generally speaking, Security event log is the next thing you need to go after.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909887